# Convert C to Pascal

Tags: c, delphi, pascal

I am converting a code written in C to Pascal. I got doubt in a part that seems to be simple but generated a doubt!

```
int Length = ...;  
void *FileBase = ...;  
if (Length && FileBase != NULL)
    ....
```

The above line with the condition "if", it means "Length" and "Filebase" are respectively different from "0" and "Null"?

it is the same as **if (Length <> 0) and (FileBase <> Nil) then** ???

Comment: Actually looking at Flz's history he/she has NOT learned to ask questions, other than bad questions. More effort on your part is required, FLZ.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a Delphi or Pascal question. It's a question about operator precedence in C. There are many references that will tell you about that. For example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence.

The key point is that `!=` has higher precedence than `&&`. So the expression

```
Length && FileBase != NULL
```

has the same meaning as

```
Length && (FileBase != NULL)
```

Since in C values are regarded as true if they are non-zero, in Delphi/Pascal this expression would be:

```
(Length <> 0) and (FileBase <> nil)
```

Comment: I find it a bit sad that each time I look for something basic like operator precedence or similar, **in C**, I often land on a C++ reference page.

Answer (score 1):

You are right – it should be translated as `if (Length <> 0) and (FileBase <> nil)`.

Comment: It's pretty clear that the asker has extracted the declarations to show us the types, but omitted the initialization/assignment of the variables.  I edited the question, and your answer, to reflect that.